# Determining stability in a time series via probabilistic modeling

Tags: time-series, bayesian, pymc

I recently started to read Probabilistic [Programming and Bayesian Methods for Hackers](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers) and really got interested in the topic and PyMC. I especially like the example of the first chapter where probabilistic programming is used to determine whether the texting behavior (quantified by the number of messages each day) changes over time.

I now thought if this could be somehow applied in similar fashion to my problem. Concretely, I have time data consisting of words added to a document. I am now interested whether this time series stabilizes over time and if so when it stabilizes. Stabilization means that the author (or authors) of the document have agreed on a set of terms and some kind of semantic stabilization is present (stasis). In literature this is often done by showing that the distribution of word frequencies is power law. Other techniques is to use for example the Kullback-Leibler divergence between time points t and t+1 and try to show that after some time the KL divergence gets lower and lower and stabilizes.

Nevertheless, these methods have some limitations and I wonder if this would be possible to solve with Probabilistic modeling. As I am not so fit with this topic yet I am curious if someone has some pointers to a possible solution if it is possible to model anyway.